# AsyncTask status is null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, status

In my android app I am using `AsyncTask`. It was working perfectly but from last 2 days my app crashed when I called .execute() of `AsyncTask`. The error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:378)
    at com.riksof.a320.remote.RemoteObject.update(RemoteObject.java:117)
    at com.fitmo.controller.activity.FitmoEditActivityDetailController.updateActivityDate(FitmoEditActivityDetailController.java:64)
    at com.fitmo.controller.activity.FitmoEditActivityDetailController.access$0(FitmoEditActivityDetailController.java:51)
    at com.fitmo.controller.activity.FitmoEditActivityDetailController$1.onClick(FitmoEditActivityDetailController.java:45)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I saw the code inside `AsyncTask.java`, I found this code inside `AsyncTask` constructor:

```
switch (mStatus)
```

So I debug the `AsyncTask` status by calling `getStatus()` method of `AsyncTask` before calling `execute()` and the value is null here as well. What can be the reason for this any ideas ?

I am not getting this every time. Some times it works properly sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You're not really giving anyone enough to go on.

Comment: @BillMote updated the full stacktrace

Comment: post some relevant code.

Comment: can you post the FitmoEditActivityDetailController.java code

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the AsyncTask myTask = new AsyncTask() by accident?

Comment: The object on which I am calling execute is not null. It seems that it calls goes inside AsyncTask constructor where it finds mStatus null

Comment: you have the problem found out. So make sure mStatus is not null